# in C#, can you detect if a USB drive hasn't been removed, then reinserted, since last app launch?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wmi

For security reasons, we're trying to detect if, when our app is restarted, a particular USB drive is still connected and hasn't been removed, nor the machine restarted, etc.

**Update**

Originally I was asking to detect if it was removed/reinserted, but that's actually backwards.  We really want to test if for sure it *hasn't* been which means we can assume the user is still authenticated.

False negatives here are fine (i.e. if we incorrectly make the assumption it was removed when it wasn't because the machine slept, powered off, etc.) as that just means the user has to re-authenticate.

False positives however (i.e. claiming it *hasn't* been removed when it actually may have been) must be avoided.  This is because if we're wrong on the first count, it's just a minor inconvenience to the end user to re-authenticate. If we're wrong on the second however, it's a potential security issue.

In short, unless we know for absolute sure it wasn't removed, we treat it like it was and they have to reauthenticate.  But if there is a way to say for sure it wasn't, then we can save them a step.

**Original Question**

Via WMI, we can tell if they unplugged it, then re-plugged it into a different port since the 'path' to the device will have changed.  But this won't handle cases where they've connected it back to the same port as before.

Another thought is if there's a way to see what time a device was connected.  If we see it's different than when we last checked, that too would be a tell. Problem is I'm not even sure that's a metric which can be queried.

Bonus if your direction/suggestion can work with *any* USB device.

Comment: Just to be sure, you don't care if it was removed and reinserted while the computer is sleeping, off, or booted into another OS, correct?

Comment: If the computer was only sleeping, then yes, I'd want to detect if it was removed/inserted there.  If you can't monitor it when sleeping, then I can treat it the same as powering off which would be automatically treated the same as removed.  You made me realize I need to reword the question because it's not so much knowing if it was removed/inserted as knowing it *wasn't* because the 'wasn't' condition means we don't have to re-prompt for security credentials.  It's ok if we error on the side of caution.

Comment: Any thoughts? is not a good question. It's too broad.

Comment: "Any thoughts" wasn't the question. It was asking if someone had any thoughts on a *specific way* to address this as I haven't found one yet.